# MongoDB: number of query

Tags: mongodb

recently, I realize that i make a lot of queries. (I think)

Edit:

I just would like to know if I can analyse how I build my app.
Using `top` linux ?
Or there are just by loading site in the browser. And use firebug for exemple to see if queries are long.
There is no server-side trick ?
Because I have for exemple a page, who load 8 queries. I think it is much. No ?

Thank you !

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Could you rephrase?

Comment: I editing. I like to know how know if i'm doing good or bad.

Comment: Still not at all clear.  Can you include an example of what you're doing that you're concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any database, it is not necessarily the total number of queries you should be concerned with so much as the query performance and efficiency of data returned by each.  Depending on your application design, data model, and indexes .. eight queries might be the expected number per page.  Regardless of the number of queries, you want to ensure the common ones are *fast*.

There are several key places you can try to understand queries in MongoDB.

In rough order of ease of use:

**1)** Use the **[explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers)** feature with a query to get more information on the query plan and use of indexes.

This should be a starting point to know whether an index is needed or is effectively used by your common queries.

**2)** You can enable the **[Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler)** for a MongoDB database.

The profiling information captured is similar to the explain() output, and includes all read/write queries.  You can set an appropriate profiling level if you only want to see slow queries rather than all.  The default for "slow queries" is 100ms but you can set this as needed.

To enable profiling for all queries from the MongoDB shell"

```
$ mongo mydb
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0-rc0
connecting to: mydb

> db.setProfilingLevel(2);
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "ok" : 1 }

> db.getProfilingLevel()
2
```

The documentation has more details on [viewing the profile data](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-ViewingtheData).

**3)** You can also try to view the query generated by your application/[driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) before it is sent to MongoDB.

Instructions  (or the possibility) for doing so are going to vary based on the driver you are using (check your driver documentation!).

**4)** Other profiling tools

There are several utility apps that will analyze your profiling data and help with index recommendations:

- [Dex - Index & Query Analyzer](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/07/remote-dex/)
- [Professor - A MongoDB Profile Viewer](http://late.am/post/2011/09/22/professor-a-mongodb-profile-viewer)

Comment: Note: Explain() is not a reliable tool to judge slow queries however

Comment: @Sammaye: Explain is useful to understand the query plan and use of indexes.  That could be one reason for queries to be slow (which is different from queries that *are* slow).  Should also mention [mongotop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongotop/) for an overview of activity.

Comment: Yea again I seem to not be explaining myself that well recently, the `millis` stated by the query is not reliable method to judge the speed of the query. Profiling tools such as the database profiler should be used instead to judge the actual time. I've seen people mistake this on the user group so thought I'd just add a note about it.

Comment: @Sammaye: I think we're trying to describe the same thing .. query plan (explain) versus execution (profiling) :).

Comment: Indeed :) I just did a fail explanation of my comment first time around

Answer (score 0):

You can check the MongoDB logs for slow queries: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging

As for the query amount - get your mind out of this SQL as-few-queries-as-possible mind set. Throw out the rule book for MongoDB. For example every time you iterate a cursor it runs the query again since it streams from the DB so you think you are running 8 queries but infact could be running 10's a second already. Mongo's results sets are not like SQLs and querying them should not be treated the same.

---

I realised that when I answered this quesiton I actually pasted the logging link not the profiling link, but @Stennie pasted the right links so it's ok.